# Select SQL where value does not exist

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a two columns `product_id` and `category_id`.
I want to select all `product_id` that don't have the `category_id = 90`

I use this query, but it returns null. What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `oc_product_to_category` 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM  `oc_product_to_category` 
  WHERE category_id = 90
)
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM  oc_product_to_category where category_id<>90`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You aren't correlating the inner and outer queries. If there's at least one product with `category_id = 90` the inner query will return some rows, and thus the `NOT EXISTS` condition will always be false, and the outer query will return no rows. You need to add a condition to specify the inner query and the outer query refer to the same product:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `oc_product_to_category` a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM   `oc_product_to_category` b
  WHERE  category_id = 90 AND
         a.product_id = b.product_id -- Here!
)
```

Comment: Thanks Mureinik, but I get this error.. #1054 - Unknown column 'oc_product_to_category.product_id' in 'order clause'  .. any idea?

Comment: I'm using aliases (`a` and `b`) to distinguish the `oc_product_to_category` in the inner query from the one in the outer query. You need to use these aliases in the `order by` clause too (i.e., `order by a.product_id`).

Comment: Thanks! it worked great after added 'order by a.product_id'

Answer (score 1):

You can query the `oc_product` table and check for products that do not have a corresponding entry in the `oc_product_to_category` table with `category_id` equal to 90.

```
SELECT *
FROM `oc_product`
WHERE product_id NOT IN
    (SELECT product_id
    FROM `oc_product_to_category`
    WHERE category_id = 90)
```

Comment: This will also return products that have more than one category, one of them being 90. I don't think that's what OP is after.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `oc_product_to_category` 
WHERE category_id <> **90**
```

Comment: This will also return products that have more than one category, one of them being 90. I don't think that's what OP is after.

Comment: Taking the assuption as each product belongs to only one category. Anyways thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `oc_product_to_category`
WHERE category_id <> 90
```

Comment: This will also return products that have more than one category, one of them being 90. I don't think that's what OP is after.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `oc_product_to_category` where product_id NOT IN (SELECT product_id
FROM  `oc_product_to_category where category_id = 90)
```

Answer (score 1):

your query should be like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `oc_product_to_category` m 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT * 
FROM  `oc_product_to_category` 
WHERE m.category_id = 90
)
```

you can get many ways those result like

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `oc_product_to_category` 
WHERE category_id <> 90




SELECT * 
FROM  `oc_product_to_category` 
WHERE category_id != 90


SELECT * 
FROM  `oc_product_to_category` 
having category_id <> 90



SELECT * 
FROM  `oc_product_to_category` 
WHERE category_id NOT IN
(SELECT * 
FROM  `oc_product_to_category` 
WHERE category_id = 90)
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * 
FROM  `oc_product_to_category` 
WHERE  `category_id` <> 90 ;

Comment: This will also return products that have more than one category, one of them being 90. I don't think that's what OP is after.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_Name 
WHERE category_id NOT LIKE '90'
```

Comment: Thanks, but this only seems to exclude the ones that have category_id = 90, not show me which ones are missing category_id = 90.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  oc_product_to_category 
WHERE category_id not in ('90')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM oc_product_to_category where category_id != 90
```

(OR)

```
SELECT * FROM oc_product_to_category where category_id <> 90
```